# Spark SQL - Incorrect conversion of oracle date data type to timestamp(java.sql) while importing from oracle

Tags: oracle, date, jdbc, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL to import data from Oracle as below-

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")  
var info : java.util.Properties = new java.util.Properties()  
info.put("user", user)  
info.put("password", password) 
val jdbcDF = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcURL, tableFullName, info)
```

Table Schema:

> SERVICE_DATE - DATE

Spark while importing converts columns having "date" data type to "java.sql.timestamp" data type. During this conversion, I am facing an issue for dates which follows daylight saving time.

**For eg:**

> oracle: SERVICE_DATE = 2008-03-09 02:49:00.0 [DATE]
>   spark: SERVICE_DATE  = 2008-03-09 03:49:00.0 [TIMESTAMP]

Is this issue with the conversion of oracle date to JDBC timestamp?

Comment: Is this solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18411/files/aefd028883bc27cd5929e80dff29d2b15aa114b2

You can see, there is a property called `oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp` which is `true` by default. If you set it to `false` the `Date` columns won't be marked as `Timestamp`.

Comment: any clue of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020103/how-to-pass-date-timestamp-as-lowerbound-upperbound-in-spark-sql-2-4-1v-with-ojd?