# How to specify timestamp values for bounds in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a table from sqlserver and apply partitioning while reading. Before reading the data, I wanted to get bounds for lowerBound & upperBound as below.

```
boundsDF = spark.read.format('jdbc')
                .option('url', 'url')
                .option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
                .option('user', username)
                .option('password', password)
                .option('dbtable', f'(select min(updated_datetime) as mint, max(updated_datetime) as maxt from tablename)
                .load()
```

I extracted the values like below from boundsDF:

```
maxdate = [x["maxt"] for x in boundsDF.rdd.collect()]
mindate = [x["mint"] for x in boundsDF.rdd.collect()]
```

And this is how I specified the timestamp columns while reading:

```
dataframe = spark.read.format('jdbc')
                 .option('url', url)
                 .option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
                 .option('user', user)
                 .option('password', password)
                 .option('dbtable', tablename)
                 .option('partitionColumn', timestamp_column)
                 .option('numPartitions', 3)
                 .option('lowerBound', mindate[0])
                 .option('upperBound', maxdate[0])
                 .option('fetchsize', 5000)
                 .load()
```

If I print the values of mindate & maxdate below is how they look like:

```
mindate[0]: datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 4, 11, 54, 13, 543000)
maxdate[0]: datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 17, 59, 45, 880000)
```

When I print `dataframe.count()`, I see an exception message as below.
Exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 18.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 21, executor driver): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Since I started using Spark, I have always used integer columns for my partition column. This is the first time I am using a timestamp column for partitioning the data.

Are mindate[0] & maxdate[0] in the right format to be specified in my read statement ?
Could anyone let me know if I am implementing the code in right manner ?

Comment: You must pass the parameter as a string using the format that SQL Server understands

Comment: But I see an error message that says cannot understand the format passed in bounds. So I thought I can try it this way.

Comment: Take a look -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020103/how-to-pass-date-timestamp-as-lowerbound-upperbound-in-spark-sql-2-4-1v-with-ojd

Comment: But that syntax is in Oracle. I am using SqlServer.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across the same issue, but after some experimentation, I was able to find the solution.

It seems there exists a bug which was raised about 2 years ago but sadly remains open to this date:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34097

However, instead of timestamp, if you pass just the date i.e. YYYY-MM-DD in **lowerBound** & **upperBound**, the code works.

Comment: thanks. i had similar issue, and settled down with date part for now.

Answer (score 1):

The question is what datatype do you use in the SQL table ?

1. TIMESTAMP is not a datetime datatype. It is an internal row version number (binary) and has nothing to do with temporal data
2. DATETIME is the old deprecated datatype for DATE + TIME and has a limitation of 3 decimal places for the second
3. DATETIME2, which replace datetime, is the new datatype to use for DATE + TIME and has a limitation that you can chosse between 0 and 7 decimal places for the second

Now two remarks:

1. if you use TIMESTAMP, replace it by DATETIME2 whith the required précision (by default 7).
2. if you use DATETIME and you do not want to replace it by DATETIME2, you must only specify 3 digits for the decimal part of the second, but what I see in your code is mindate[0]: datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 4, 11, 54, 13, *543000*)

DATETIME2 is more accurate than DATETIME that is limited to 3 ms causing some queries to be badly interpreted

Comment: I understood your explanation. But when I give datatime values are my bounds, I am facing the exception I mentioned in the question.

Comment: As I say, if you use DATETIME and you do not want to replace it by DATETIME2, you must only specify 3 digits for the decimal part of the second, so modify this code : mindate[0]: datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 4, 11, 54, 13, 543000), by if you use DATETIME and you do not want to replace it by datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 4, 11, 54, 13, 543)

Comment: Regarding your answer's point number 2 in remarks section, Spark by default is reading that date column in the format of datetime.datetime. You are suggesting that I change the existing format of Datetime to Datetime2. If I have to convert it to Datetime2, I should also cast the entire column to Datetime2 while reading data by Spark because I am giving the partition bounds in that specific format. 
Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I think so, but you must try