# How to fix the exception: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string on Spark reading data from SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I am trying to read data from a table on SQLServer database using and ingest into bigquery as below.

```
val dataframe = spark.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", s"url")
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "pwd")
  .option("dbtable", s"(select * from $tablename where insertTime >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and insertTime <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59') as dateDF")
  .option("partitionColumn", insertTime)
  .option("numPartitions", 4)
  .option("lowerBound", "2020-01-01 00:00:00")
  .option("upperBound", "2020-12-31 23:59:59")
  .load()
```

And saving this dataframe as

```
dataframe.write.format("bigquery").option("table", s"gcsbucketlocation:default_dataset.dummytesttable").mode("append").save()
```

The partitionColumn: `insertTime` is of type: `datetime` on Sqlserver and as per Spark's latest [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) the column: `insertTime` is a valid one to be a partitionColumn.

But when I submit the job, I see that converstion of String to Time stamp is failed according to this error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    .....
    .....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to write to BigQuery
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:93)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.insert(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:42)
    at com.poc.ingestion.SaveToBigQuery.$anonfun$read_and_ingest$1(SaveToBigQuery.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158)
    at com.poc.ingestion.SaveToBigQuery.read_and_ingest(SaveToBigQuery.scala:23)
    at com.poc.Trigger$.main(Trigger.scala:46)
    at com.poc.Trigger.main(Trigger.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I tried to give various formats of date:

Case 1:
`2020-01-01 00:00:00 000` and `2020-01-01 00:00:00.000` and `2020-01-01 00:00:00:000`

Case 2:
I also tried to convert the String to Timestamp and give the timestamp instead. But it is not accepted in options of Spark and `Long`, `Double`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Map[Sometype1, sometype2]`
and I get a compilation error `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'option'`

Case 3:
`.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")`

There are other questions for the same but their source database is Oracle and those are suggestions could not be used as solution(s) in this case.

For example, theis suggestion doesn't work:
`.option("oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp", "false")` since the database I am reading from is SqlServer.

I am using these jars to read & write data from Sqlserver.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-bigquery_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>0.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried all the cases and running into the same issue again and again.
Am I using the correct jars and drivers ?
How can I specify the timestamp properly in `lowerBound` & `upperBound` and also inside the query of `dbtable` while reading data from Sqlserver ?
Can anyone let me know what is the mistake I did here and how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you use [DATEFROMPARTS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)? Otherwise you might need to insert `set dateformat mdy;` at the beginning of your statement because it sounds like the server or connection defaults to `set dateformat dmy;`.

Comment: How can I use DATEFROMPARTS here ? I can only apply the datatypes I mentioned above..

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77469695/9317929), check my solution there.