# Spark conversion error on the executor JDBC SQLSERVER partition option

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java, spark-jdbc

I'm first reading lower bound and upper bound using a:

```
select max(timestamp) ,min(timestamp) from table name
```

extracting
`Row row=query.collectasList().get(0).getString(0) as lowerbound and upperbound`
respectively
then passing lowerbound and upper bound

```
spark.read("jdbc")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", "sample")
  .option("user", user)
  .option("driver","com.sqlserver")
  .option("password", password)
  .option("numPartitions", 100)
  .option("partitionColumn", "timestamp")
  .option("lowerBound", lowerbound)
  .option("upperBound", upperbound )
lowerbound and upperbound format "2022-02-09 17:13:22.353"
```

I understand lowerbound and upper bound has to be string but when passed I'm facing the below issue can you please help?
Facing this issue Lost task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, , executor 1):

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java

Comment: ISO 8601 is the safest date format for SQL Server.  See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813238/tsql-datetime-iso-8601

Comment: You're missing a `T`. If you're on an SQL Server using `DMY` format, e.g. `set dateformat dmy; select cast('2022-02-09 17:13:22.353' as datetime);`, then your string will incorrectly be interepreted at 02-Sep-2022. This exchange will cause the error message in your question when months 13 through 31 are involved. Using a proper ISO format including the `T` will not experience that issue, e.g.: `set dateformat dmy; select cast('2022-02-09T17:13:22.353' as datetime);`

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77469695/9317929), check my solution there.